# Configuring additional properties within SnowflakeBasicDataSource

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using following class in Java. But this class has limited implementation of properties.

```
SnowflakeBasicDataSource basicDataSource = new SnowflakeBasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setSsl(true);
    basicDataSource.setUser(dbSnowFlakeUsername);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(dbSnowFlakePassword);
    basicDataSource.setUrl(dbSnowFlakeUrl);
    basicDataSource.setLoginTimeout(dbSnowFlakeLoginTimeoutSeconds);
```

For example i want to indicate networkTimeout and queryTimeout. But this is not implemented

How do i pass it to SnowflakeBasicDataSource?

Tried to pass withing url like this

```
jdbc:snowflake://ni31094.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=TEST_DB&schema=PUBLIC&role=SYSADMIN&warehouse=TEST_WAREHOUSE&tracing=FINE&networkTimeout=10&queryTimeout=10
```

But don't think it works.

Please need assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The two parameters for Network and Query Timeout are:

- Network Timeout: `networkTimeout`
- Query Timeout: `queryTimeout=<number>`

Looking at your string: Yes, you are using the two parameters correctly but I see your user and password-parameters are missing.

You can also try to:

- ensure your properties are set correctly
- adjust your connection string and accountinformation-values

You can find some more detail information about troubleshooting here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#troubleshooting-tips

Comment: Thanks Marcel for the answer, but yes i do use passwrod and username. They are injected via methods of SnowflakeBasicDataSource  class. The question was whether those two parameters in url will be used or ignored. 
I can tell that i have connection and everything works fine. I just want to implement these two parameters but not with Connection > Statetement chain.

Comment: They aren't ignored usually.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? For your queryTimeout=10 do a query that takes 1 min for example and you should get a timeout message.

Comment: For example , i set to 10 seconds to networkTimeout as in my url string. Then i just disconnect from network lan and it's only invoked after something one minute.

Comment: This relates to something else... the default for network timeout is 0 seconds and not 1 minute.

Comment: Default is 60 seconds from documentation of snowflake

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#troubleshooting-tips
according to this webpage, the default for network timeout is 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the properties in the URL for the `SnowflakeBasicDataSource` does work. I tested the `queryTimeout` with a long-running query and the query correctly get cancelled after the specified time in the parameter.

Testing `networkTimeout` is a little more difficult since it's hard to tell how it is actually used. It is used by `net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest` and I've tested that the correct parameter gets passed through, and it does. The reason you're getting a timeout of 60 seconds is that the HTTP request for the initial login request gets set to that by default. The initial login request seems to ignore the `networkTimeout`. The request which contains the query to run gets correctly set to the `networkTimeout` parameter passed in through the query string. Since my java skills aren't great I was unable to test a situation where the `networkTimeout` causes an error, unfortunately.

Here is some scala code which shows you that the two params get correctly set in the session:

```scala
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.{SnowflakeBasicDataSource, SnowflakeConnectionV1}

import java.sql.Statement
import java.io.FileReader
import java.util.Properties

object BasicConnector extends App{
  val prop = new Properties
  prop.load(new FileReader("~/snowflake_conn.properties"))

  val username = prop.getProperty("username")
  val password = prop.getProperty("password")
  val url = prop.getProperty("url") + "?networkTimeout=54321&queryTimeout=1234"

  val basicDataSource = new SnowflakeBasicDataSource()
  basicDataSource.setSsl(true)
  basicDataSource.setUser(username)
  basicDataSource.setPassword(password)
  basicDataSource.setUrl(url)
  basicDataSource.setWarehouse("DEMO_WH")

  val conn: SnowflakeConnectionV1 = basicDataSource.getConnection().asInstanceOf[SnowflakeConnectionV1]
  val statement: Statement = conn.createStatement()

  val queryTimeout = conn.getSfSession.getQueryTimeout
  val networkTimeout = conn.getSfSession.getNetworkTimeoutInMilli

  println(s"query timeout: $queryTimeout")
  println(s"network timeout: $networkTimeout")

  statement.close()
  conn.close()
```

The above prints out:

```
query timeout: 1234
network timeout: 54321
```

As you can see, I had to cast the Connection object to a `SnowflakeConnectionV1` and use the `getSfSession` method to inspect the params with `.asInstanceOf[SnowflakeConnectionV1]`. This is because the JDBC `Connection` type doesn't have this method. You shouldn't have to do this though if you don't care about inspecting the parameter, it'll still use them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your tests.. It's very interesting what you say, but still strange that when i use Connection>Statement chain then it throws network error much more quickly than via  SnowflakeBasicDataSource class. 
Also, If we look at SnowflakeBasicDataSource  class inside then no seen any implementation of setting these two parameters while others yes.

Comment: Also, it's not clear from snowflake documentation

`networkTimeout
Specifies how long to wait for a response when interacting with the Snowflake service before returning an error. Zero (0) indicates no network timeout is set.

Default is 0 seconds.

queryTimeout=<number>
Specifies how long to wait for a query to complete before returning an error. Zero (0) indicates to wait indefinitely.

Default is 0 seconds.`

But conn.getSfSession.getNetworkTimeoutInMilli shows me what i put in query networkTimeout=10, so it should display 10000 ms